# Why am I receiving this error: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')

Tags: python, mysql

I'm receiving the above error, which I believe implies I'm passing in the wrong type as I add rows to my table.  However, I'm creating the new table using columns from two other tables and I'm using the same types as specified in the original tables. What am I missing?

First I create the table:

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lens_items;")
query = '''
CREATE TABLE lens_items (
    solution_id INTEGER(9),
    task_id BIGINT(20),
    item_oid CHAR(48),
    influence DOUBLE
);
'''
cur.execute(query)
```

Next I create a new table by looping over queries and adding the row results to the new table (lens_items).  I INSERT at "######>>>>>" below:

```
cursor1 = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)  # a dictcursor enables a named hash
cursor2 = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)  # a dictcursor enables a named hash

query = """
    Select user_id, solution_id 
    From user_concepts
    Where user_id IN (Select user_id FROM fields);
"""  

cursor1.execute(query)

rows1 = cursor1.fetchall()
######>>>>>

for row in rows1:
    user_id = row["user_id"]
    solution_id = row["solution_id"]

    cursor2.execute("""
        INSERT INTO lens_items (solution_id, task_id, item_oid, influence)
        VALUES (solution_id, (SELECT task_id, item_oid, influence
        FROM solution_oids 
        WHERE task_id = %s
        ORDER BY influence DESC));
    """, (solution_id,))
```

Comment: the pattern is insert into tableName (col list) select stmt. You would not have a `values` word and make it work. See [Manual Page Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: I'm using the same column names as the variable names. I didn't think that was a problem. Is that what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: it's a syntax error. Let's say it wasn't one hypothetically. Where in the world is `solution_id` coming from ! It is not important what layer of python middleware is making you think it is just barely close enough by not showing a syntax error 1064. It is simply malformed

Comment: omg. yes. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the original error message was caused by the extra comma after solution_id in the **python code**  right at the end of the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not follow mysql syntax for INSERT, since you try to mix the values clause with a select. Use [INSERT ... SELECT ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) instead:

```
    INSERT INTO lens_items (solution_id, task_id, item_oid, influence)
    SELECT solution_id, task_id, item_oid, influence
    FROM solution_oids 
    WHERE task_id = %s
    ORDER BY influence DESC
```

However, you could simplify the data transfer if you used join in the select part leaving python completely out of the picture:

```
    INSERT INTO lens_items (solution_id, task_id, item_oid, influence)
    SELECT s.solution_id, s.task_id, s.item_oid, s.influence
    FROM solution_oids s
    INNER JOIN user_concepts u ON s.solution_id=u.solution_id
    INNER JOIN fields f ON f.user_id=u.user_id
    ORDER BY influence DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show him various formats